# How can I render component that gets rendered when clicking a button to the top of the list instead of the bottom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question. I have these code snippets implemented in my class component and while it is working for the most part, I need to actual display the most recent rendered component on top of the list instead of appended to the bottom of the list. How can I do that easily?

Code snippets:

```
state = {
    formCount: 0
   }
   
   //click event for button
   onAddClicked = () => { 
       this.setState({formCount: this.state.formCount + 1});
   }

    //render components based on count 
   { [...Array(this.state.formCount)].map((_, i) => <Form key={i}/>)}
```

So I have form count in state and on clicking on a button, it will increment the count and then depending on the count, it will render the same component whenever I click on the button.
However, right now it is adding the new components to the bottom instead of the top, how do I render the new component that gets rendered when clicking the button to the top of the list instead?

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to render components based on data structure? Then it's trivial, for example to add one or more elements to the beginning of an array `.unshift({...})`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, can you elaborate what you mean by adding elements to the array. Do you mean the component or ?

Comment: Instead of representing number of forms as number use `array`, it's easier because it is represented on page in same way.. you don't loose mapping in your mind, acepted solution just convert number to this structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.reverse()` along with `.keys()`:

```js
[...Array(this.state.formCount).keys()].reverse().map((i) => <Form key={i}/>)
```

Comment: @Euridice01 what do you mean by mutating the object you've rendered? It will not mutate the existing `Form`: https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions67590130-pberk?file=/index.js

Comment: Actually, the mutate issue was on my end sorry. It wasn't working before thought but not sure why, probs my fault. Thanks! It is working now :D Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to render the components in reverse order? With the most "recent" ones at the top? A simple way would be to `.reverse()` the array of components

Comment: reverse doesn't work. The newest item is still adding to the bottom